# Undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3pcl7console5printENS0_15VERBOSITY_LEVELEPKcz' in c++ for point cloud library

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am simply trying to compile a program from [this](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php) link.
I already linked all the necessary libraries but this one I can't find. All I am getting is the following error in codeblocks (also in eclipse).

> undefined reference to symbol
> '_ZN3pcl7console5printENS0_15VERBOSITY_LEVELEPKcz'

Anybody know how to get rid of this error? Or even which library it require?
PS: I already tried to link *pcl_console*, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using `CMake` to generate your project?